# Bulk Import aborted error

Tags: magento

I have try to bulk import values of attributes, my excel consists 60's of records, when completed 43 records its aborted.

[screen shots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9XMg.png)

Comment: did you my excel sheet

Comment: http://wikisend.com/download/780714/import_product_attributes.csv

Comment: I'm from mobile currently, what error do you get when importing that file?

Comment: this is my error     http://i.stack.imgur.com/rcpqr.png

Comment: is it me or do I see many empty red rows?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?